# Sending FormData with Axios Patch Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am attempting to update some user information in my database through my API built with nodejs; with someData from a html form using an axios patch request.

code:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('key1',someData.value);
formData.append('key2',someData.value);
formData.append('key3',someData.value);

try {
  const res = await axios({ method: 'PATCH', someUrl, formData})
} catch (err) {
  log(err)
}
```

I am attempting to update some user information in my database through my API with someData from a html form using an axios patch request.

Problem #1 request body is empty when the data gets to my controller.

I also tried...

```
data: {
 key1: formData.get('key1'),
 key2: formData.get('key2'),
 key3: formData.get('key3'),
}
```

Problem #2 The above works inside the axios request
but the keys may not always be the same. I want to be able to use this function to update password, user information, or some other field that the user may want to patch.

I also declared and empty LET Object:

```
let formData = {}
```

and stored the list of someData values into this empty object.

Problem #3 I was able to update the user data but I don't know if it is bad practice to use a let variable to solve this issue. I feel like I am possibly exposing data that could be manipulated because I'm using a lET variable.

Expected Result:
Axios Patch Request sends accessible FormData to API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably attempting to update file data(ie: images). Try including a headers option in your axios call back function to specify the content type of the formData you are including in your patch request within a headers option. For file data like images you will need to specify the content-type: 'multipart/form-data' within a headers option.

```
const updateSettings = async(data, type) => {
  try {
    const url =
      type !== 'fileData'
        ? 'http://yourDomain/user/updateStringData'
        : 'http://yourDomain/user/updateFileData';
    const res =
      type !== 'fileData'
        ? await axios({ method: 'PATCH', url, data })
        : await axios({
            method: 'PATCH',
            url,
            data,
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
      });
   } catch(err) { 
      console.log(err)
   }
};

const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('key1',someData.value);
formData.append('key2',someData.value);
formData.append('key3',someData.file[0]);

updateSettings(formData, 'fileData');
```